# Error: .ini file does not include supervisorctl section in UBUNTU

Tags: supervisord

I have installed supervisor in my ubuntu-18. But when i type the command supervisorctl, [enter image description here][1]It's through a Error as Error: .ini file does not include supervisorctl section and some times http://localhost:9001 refused connection.
when i type the command sudo supervisorctl it thorough a error pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'supervisor==3.3.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?